# make the price of one line the price of all lines

Tags: mysql

I just started using mysql for SAP.

I would like to get this result:

```
DocEntry Description Price
00001    item A      100.00
00003    item C      110.00
```

From this data

```
DocEntry  Description Quantity Price
00001     item A       2       300.00
00001     freight      -       100.00
00002     item A       1       300.00
00003     item C       1       300.00
00003     freight      -       110.00
```

I tried to filter the items with freight through this:

```
create view table_a 
as 
select DocEntry, Description, Price 
from inv1 where Description like 'freight'

create view table_b 
as 
select DocEntry, Description, Price
from inv1
where exist (select * from table_a where table_a.DocEntry = table_b.DocEntry
```

I don't know though what to do with price?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by, **"make the price of one line the price of all lines"**?

Comment: Doesn't `SELECT DocEntry, Description, Price FROM inv1 WHERE Description = 'freight'` get you what you what you want?

Comment: do any DocEntries have more than 2 records? if so what descriptions do we have on those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want the freight fit each item:

```
select distinct a.DocEntry, a.Description, b.Price
from inv1 a
join inv1 b on a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
where a.Description != 'freight'
and b.Description = 'freight'
```

although the data does not require it, the `distinct` keyword has been added in case there are multiple "item" rows for each "freight" row. If the is no possibility of that ever happening, `distinct` may be removed.

Comment: This works provided descriptions are limited to 2 for each docEntry; otherwise the !='freight' will not be sufficient.  (And assuming the ' on the second `'freight` is added to the end)

Comment: @xQbert OK then, added `distinct`

Comment: I wasn't clear.  The only syntax issue is a missing ' at the very end.  The other issue is if the user has more than the 2 entries listed for description per docEntry. (not listed in example) if they do, this won't work.  Otherwise its fine.  and here's an example of why distinct may not work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1c75/1/0.  But the OP needs to provide more data if that's the case.  This is a +1 answer just missing a ' at end and a question on logic for the OP.

Comment: @xQbert you can sleep easy now; the closing quote has been added :) thx

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're asking, but maybe something like this...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(DocEntry INT NOT NULL,  Description VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL, Quantity INT NULL,Price INT NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(DocEntry,Description));

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'item A',2,300),
(1,'freight',NULL,100),
(2,'item A',1,300),
(3,'item C',1,300),
(3,'freight',NULL,110);

mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table;
+----------+-------------+----------+-------+
| DocEntry | Description | Quantity | Price |
+----------+-------------+----------+-------+
|        1 | freight     |     NULL |   100 |
|        1 | item A      |        2 |   300 |
|        2 | item A      |        1 |   300 |
|        3 | freight     |     NULL |   110 |
|        3 | item C      |        1 |   300 |
+----------+-------------+----------+-------+

SELECT docentry
     , MAX(CASE WHEN description = 'freight' THEN price END) price
     , MAX(CASE WHEN quantity IS NOT NULL THEN description END) description 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY docentry 
HAVING price IS NOT NULL;
+----------+-------+-------------+
| docentry | price | description |
+----------+-------+-------------+
|        1 |   100 | item A      |
|        3 |   110 | item C      |
+----------+-------+-------------+
```